# Run another executable in my Qt app

Tags: c++, qt, executable, qprocess

I wrote two Qt applications. One is the main and the other is a side way.

I am running Linux. 
I read about `QProcess` so I wrote this code:

```
 QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.show();
    QProcess P(&w);
    QString programPath;
    programPath=
    "/Documents/Qt/test1-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release/test1";
    P.start(programPath);

    return a.exec();
```

However, nothing happens and just my main app (`w`) runs.

What is my fault? 
Please help me.

Comment: Connect signals
`void  error ( QProcess::ProcessError error );
void  finished ( int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus ex);
void  started ();
void  stateChanged ( QProcess::ProcessState newState );` to see what happened

Comment: @kassak That should be an actual answer :)

Comment: QObject::connect(&P,SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)),); you mean this? what should  i write for third parameter ? i mean how to see this signals result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault was in the path to executable.

I edit it, very simple and got it work.

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();
QProcess P(&w);
QString programPath;
programPath=
    "/home/erfan/Documents/Qt/test1-build-desktop- Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release/test1";
P.start(programPath);
return a.exec();
```

And it work properly.

Another way is to put the executable directly in root:

> `(/ somthings)`

Comment: dont put your executable in the root. just dont

Answer (score 3):

the issue is that  `P.start(programPath);` is a non blocking operation. Furthermore, the application output is redirected , and can be accessible from the Qprocess object ***only***.

**Edit:**

It seems that the path to the executable is incorrect. Anything which starts with **"/"** will be considered an absolute path.

You probably need to write a `QObject` subclass to monitor the process you started. This object will catch process signals as kassak pointed out.

```
class ProcessMonitor : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT

public slots:

void notifyStart();

void handleError( QProcess::ProcessError error );

void notifyStop(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus ex);
}
```

In each slot you can just print a message. Then you can do the connections

```
ProcessMonitor montinor;
QObject::connect(&P,SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)), 
      &monitor,SLOT(handleError( QProcess::ProcessError error )) );
```

Comment: both my app are Gui , and i want to run both of them geraphicaly. i mean when second app run fist app steal run. how can i do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
#include <cstdlib>
std::system("/path/to/executable &");
```

Comment: That won't fix the OP's problem. If QProcess wasn't able to execute the binary, std::system() won't be able to either. Furthermore, your code is less portable (which systems recognize `&`?)